# iText Create Signed PDF using external Signature WebService

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, signature, pades

I try to implement signing a PDF with an external signature webService in iText.
I used the example Client-Server-Signing provided by iText (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/itext/i5ns-tutorial/master/signatures/chapter4/C4_07_ClientServerSigning/C4_07_ClientServerSigning.cs) as a blueprint.

```
public class ServerSignature : IExternalSignature
{
    public String GetHashAlgorithm()
    {
        return DigestAlgorithms.SHA256;
    }

    public String GetEncryptionAlgorithm()
    {
        return "ECDSA";
        //return "1.2.840.10045.4.3.2";
    }

    public byte[] Sign(byte[] message)
    {
        string base64encodedMessage = Convert.ToBase64String(message);

        // upload to WebService and return response

        return Convert.FromBase64String(signatureValueFromWebServiceResponse)
    }
}
```

In method public byte[] sign(byte[] message) I upload the receveived message to a webservice using the following Request

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<CreateXMLSignatureRequest xmlns='http://www.buergerkarte.at/namespaces/securitylayer/1.2#'>
    <KeyboxIdentifier>SecureSignatureKeypair</KeyboxIdentifier>
    <DataObjectInfo Structure='detached'>
        <DataObject>
            <Base64Content>_BASE_64_ENCODED_MESSAGE_GOES_HERE_</Base64Content>
        </DataObject>
        <TransformsInfo>
            <FinalDataMetaInfo>
                <MimeType>application/octet-stream</MimeType>
            </FinalDataMetaInfo>
        </TransformsInfo>
    </DataObjectInfo>   
</CreateXMLSignatureRequest>
```

from the received response I return the base64-decoded value of dsig:SignatureValue. But the signature in the resultant pdf is invalid.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<sl:CreateXMLSignatureResponse xmlns:sl="http://www.buergerkarte.at/namespaces/securitylayer/1.2#">
    <dsig:Signature xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="signature-1-1">
        <dsig:SignedInfo>
            <dsig:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
            <dsig:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#ecdsa-sha256"/>
            <dsig:Reference Id="reference-1-1" URI="#signed-data-1-1">
                <dsig:Transforms>
                    <dsig:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2002/06/xmldsig-filter2">
                        <xpf:XPath xmlns:xpf="http://www.w3.org/2002/06/xmldsig-filter2" Filter="intersect">id('signed-data-1-1')/node()</xpf:XPath>
                    </dsig:Transform>
                    <dsig:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#base64"/>
                </dsig:Transforms>
                <dsig:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                <dsig:DigestValue>7jsgSqDrGHnQkoM4DbxMl8zrw2uOPDCKssM40dbsnG4=</dsig:DigestValue>
            </dsig:Reference>
            <dsig:Reference Id="etsi-data-reference-1-1" Type="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.1.1#SignedProperties" URI="">
                <dsig:Transforms>
                    <dsig:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2002/06/xmldsig-filter2">
                        <xpf:XPath xmlns:xpf="http://www.w3.org/2002/06/xmldsig-filter2" Filter="intersect" xmlns:etsi="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.1.1#">//*[@Id='etsi-signed-1-1']/etsi:QualifyingProperties/etsi:SignedProperties</xpf:XPath>
                    </dsig:Transform>
                </dsig:Transforms>
                <dsig:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                <dsig:DigestValue>AJjWF42gp3Tqlm1e48cFpEag6qimlxxNLJCN3ifdILo=</dsig:DigestValue>
            </dsig:Reference>
        </dsig:SignedInfo>
        <dsig:SignatureValue>OOf0hDYe3iviLhhI+ILVzDBMdFe81dyQ9wvGlJoPqK8x8EJ307sNhf6Ek+tG769BB5dwc4cfdA+FdImq32zCrw==</dsig:SignatureValue>
        <dsig:KeyInfo>
            <dsig:X509Data>
                <dsig:X509Certificate>MIIFm[...]RLIq62uftJSg==</dsig:X509Certificate>
            </dsig:X509Data>
        </dsig:KeyInfo>
        <dsig:Object Id="signed-data-1-1">MYGRMBgGCSqGSIb3DQEJAzELBgkqhkiG9w0BBwEwLwYJKoZIhvcNAQkEMSIEIKIfaQzzGO9vOx1dur+Rj8cLeE2YGq/0a3yiOSrhOPIyMEQGCyqGSIb3DQEJEAIvMTUwMzAxMC8wCwYJYIZIAWUDBAIBBCAr+qi8RnPA0LmY6f0eQiHiJSypOC4h8FIOOPMMN9TFsA==</dsig:Object>
        <dsig:Object Id="etsi-signed-1-1">
            <etsi:QualifyingProperties xmlns:etsi="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.1.1#" Target="#signature-1-1">
                <etsi:SignedProperties>
                    <etsi:SignedSignatureProperties>
                        <etsi:SigningTime>2019-11-10T23:00:45Z</etsi:SigningTime>
                        <etsi:SigningCertificate>
                            <etsi:Cert>
                                <etsi:CertDigest>
                                    <etsi:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                                    <etsi:DigestValue>2wlg8N3c1NxfsP3JJs9V/VJevH8=</etsi:DigestValue>
                                </etsi:CertDigest>
                                <etsi:IssuerSerial>
                                    <dsig:X509IssuerName>CN=a-sign-premium-mobile-05,OU=a-sign-premium-mobile-05,O=A-Trust Ges. f. Sicherheitssysteme im elektr. Datenverkehr GmbH,C=AT</dsig:X509IssuerName>
                                    <dsig:X509SerialNumber>548505616</dsig:X509SerialNumber>
                                </etsi:IssuerSerial>
                            </etsi:Cert>
                        </etsi:SigningCertificate>
                        <etsi:SignaturePolicyIdentifier>
                            <etsi:SignaturePolicyImplied/>
                        </etsi:SignaturePolicyIdentifier>
                    </etsi:SignedSignatureProperties>
                    <etsi:SignedDataObjectProperties>
                        <etsi:DataObjectFormat ObjectReference="#reference-1-1">
                            <etsi:MimeType>application/octet-stream</etsi:MimeType>
                        </etsi:DataObjectFormat>
                    </etsi:SignedDataObjectProperties>
                </etsi:SignedProperties>
            </etsi:QualifyingProperties>
        </dsig:Object>
    </dsig:Signature>
</sl:CreateXMLSignatureResponse>
```

does anybody know how I need to modify my code to generate valid signed pdfs?

Answer (score 0):

If I see that correctly (I'm not that good with XML signatures, I'm more into CMS signatures), your XML signature signs two chunks of data,

- first the content of the `dsig:Object` with ID `signed-data-1-1`, base64-decoded, and
- then the `etsi:SignedProperties` in the `dsig:Object` with ID `etsi-signed-1-1`.

For the use case at hand, though, you'd need a signature of only the first part. But I doubt the signing service request for an *XML signature* (you use `CreateXMLSignatureRequest` after all) will allow you to not include any XML meta information at all.

I'd propose you instead try to use `CreateCMSSignatureRequest` to create a CMS signature container which you can embed completely into the PDF using iText 7. Beware, you'll need a `IExternalSignatureContainer` implementation instead of the `IExternalSignature` above.

Depending on the exact signature type you want you may try and execute the `CreateCMSSignatureRequest` call with `PAdESCompatibility` set to `true`.

You may want to take a look at [Die österreichische Bürgerkarte](https://www.buergerkarte.at/konzept/securitylayer/spezifikation/20140114/) and in particular the [Schnittstellenspezifikation](https://www.buergerkarte.at/konzept/securitylayer/spezifikation/20140114/core/Core-1.2.xsd).